# Converting python to R - clustering

Tags: r

I created a file with 40 binary values preceeded by the name, i'm trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252127/r-cluster-analysis-on-binary-weblog-data/30252591#30252591), its super easy and exactly what I need.
I do not know R though so i'm just trying to copy the example exactly: but I keep getting the `error: "line 1 did not have 42 elements"`

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, row.names = 1, text = "name a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a15 a16 a17 a18 a19 a20 a21 a22 a23 a24 a25 a26 a27 a28 a29 a30 a31 a32 a33 a34 a35 a36 a37 a38 a39 a40
077 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
3FF 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
AAS 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Ale 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ali 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Alt 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Ama 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ano 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Aro 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Be1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Be2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Bli 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Bri 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Bro 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Chi 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Cit 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Col 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Con 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Cra 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Cur 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Doe 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Do1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Do2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Do3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Do4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Do5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Due 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Ele 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Fa1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Fa2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Foc 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Fou 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Fur 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Fuz 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Gr1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Gr2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Gre 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Gre 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Hal 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Har 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Hea 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Hit 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Ho1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ho2 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Ho3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ho4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ho5 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ho6 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Inn 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ind 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Jad 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
JJJ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Jul 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Jus 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Lum 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Lun 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Mag 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Mak 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Man 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Mas 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Mel 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Moo 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Mon 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Mos 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Mut 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Nel 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
OBr 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Ode 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Ora 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Per 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Pom 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Pro 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Pse 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Rec 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Red 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
RPM 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Sap 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Sar 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Sch 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Scu 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
St1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
St2 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
St3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
Str 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
Sum 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Su1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Su2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Sus 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Th1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Th2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Th3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Tod 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Tri 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Tro 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Two 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Uni 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
Wet 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Whi 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
Yel 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
Zee 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0")
```

but...ive counted twice and the values in row.names is the same length as the rows?

Comment: works fine for me.

Comment: of course it does ;-;

Comment: I added the full data set, can you see if it still works for you?  I didn't think the length would make a difference but clearly something is different somewhere.

Comment: Running that line of code makes my R crash

Comment: `Gre` is repeated twice, so you cannot use `row.names`. Changing `Gre` to `Grx` fixed it and now the above runs fine for me.

Comment: hallelujah thank you!